# Задать стиль элементу input в виде картинки с помощью css

Tags: css3, html5, input

Как задать стиль текста всему списку  элементов  input? [image: к примеру поменять стиль надписи email]

Код:

```
<ul>
    <li><input  type="text" value="Email" ></li>
    <li><input type="text" value="Username" name="Username"></li>
    <li><input type="text" value="Password"></li>
    <li><input type="text"  value= "Confirm Password"></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="LET'S GO"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ul li input[type="text"] { color: #ff0000; }`

Comment: @InDevX Большое спасибо!

Comment: Только обычно этот текст записывают в placeholder, а не в value

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать для всех ваших элементов input один класс, затем с помощью css задайте нужный вам образ для этого класса.

```css
input.myclass { /* input с классом myclass */
    color: navy; /* Синий цвет текста */
}
```

```html
<li><input type="text" class="myclass" value="Password"></li>
<li><input type="text"  class="myclass" value= "Confirm Password"></li>
<li><input type="submit" class="myclass" value="LET'S GO"></li>
```